# Object Required: VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range that I am transposing and assigning to a listbox with rowsource. I get the error 'Object required' when I run my program on the line where I assign my range (TSelected_Range) to rowsource. Any idea?

```
Set Selected_Range = WS_Sel.Range(WS_Sel.Cells(2, 1), WS_Sel.Cells(counter + 1, LstCol1))
Dim TSelected_Range As Variant
TSelected_Range = Application.Transpose(Selected_Range)

With TabData.DataTable
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnCount = counter + 1
    .RowSource = TSelected_Range.Value   ********errors here 
End With
```

Comment: Declare the TSelected_Range as a `Range` instead of a `Variant`? e.g. `Dim TSelected_Range As Range`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you I used an array and the List property instead:

```
Set Selected_Range = WS_Sel.Range(WS_Sel.Cells(2, 1), WS_Sel.Cells(counter + 1, LstCol1))
Dim TSelected_Range() As Variant
TSelected_Range = Selected_Range.Value
TSelected_Range = Application.Transpose(TSelected_Range)

With TabData.DataTable
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnCount = counter + 1
    .List = TSelected_Range   
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

use `List` property

```
With TabData.DataTable
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnCount = counter + 1
    .List = TSelected_Range
End With
```

Comment: Still says 'Object required' :(

Comment: I assumed that `TabData` is the name of the UserForm and `DataTable` is the name of a ListBox control inside it

Comment: I wouldn't say why. That code worked for me assuming your exact variables dimmings and settings.